Auto adjust the font size of a container so that the text is only one line but takes up the entire container width (CSS only)
Say I have a text container, can the font auto adjust so that the text inside fits in exactly one line and takes up the entire container width without overflowing? With only CSS.
Like hypothetically if I had a  and I set the font size to auto, and auto did the thing I described earlier.
(Note: This isn't a duplicate of this other question, because the solution to that question doesn't make the text fit in exactly one line and the font still has to be set to a magic number like 1em or 2em.)

With a monospaced font and a known number of characters and using container units, possibly. For the general case JavaScript would be needed.

Unfortunately, CSS alone does not support automatically adjusting the font size to perfectly fit the text within the container's width and extend it to a single line without overflowing. However, you can try using a combination of viewport units like vw to adjust the text size based on the container's width.

Not an answer, because it's not CSS only, but you might be interested in Big As.
